# Count characters with a list within a list from a csv file

Tags: python

I have a csv file when read in the shell looks like

`data = [['Jack'],['Jill'],['Jane']]`

I am trying to count the number of characters for each name and output to `[4,4,4]`. I have tried `[len(i) for i in data]` but it returns `[1,1,1]`.

Comment: you have a list of lists so when you do `len(i)` you are getting the length of the list the the content, try `i[0]`

Comment: remember it's a list of lists with strings.

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of lists which you can flatten out.
This should work:

```
[len(i) for l in data for i in l]
```